# django model to access database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Request some help from django community.
I am new to Django. My requirement is

1. create a DRF which will execute a stored procedure in an existing database( Master data management in MS SQL database) and list down the records .
2. further when we navigate to each record from point number 1 we display  the details of the records with more fields.

I have already created a function which uses `pyodbc` in my `view.py` file to achieve the result and the display the values. 
But I have read some article where it is mentioned that as a best practice it is always better to define a model and then a serializer to define the data structure and display them. 
Questions:

1. Is it a correct approach to define a model for the above scenario.
2. As per my knowledge whenever we create a model it creates a database table which I don't want (as I have the database already with all the necessary table and data). So if point 1 is yes then can you give reference build the model which will not create the table.
3. Further to the above requirement I would like to connect multiple database (one MS SQL database and one oracle database and one content management database) where, all these models should be for read only purpose and my model should not create any new table.

Thanks in advance.

I am currently using this code to achieve point 1:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}; Server=servername; PORT:60755; Database=databasename; Trusted_Connection=yes;user=user; Passoword=password")


def ClientListView(request):
    print("read")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    ClientObjlist = conn.execute("exec [Database].[dbo].[Storedprocedure]  @doccount = '50'")
    description = ClientObjlist.description

    items = []
    items = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in description], row)) for row in ClientObjlist]
    columnheader = [key[0] for key in description]
    return render(request, 'api/activelist.html', {'items': items , 'key':columnheader})
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a Model without creating a new table. This is how you do it:

```
class MySP(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_sp'
```

For more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: Hi Thanks for the idea. I will try that. Any way  I can mention the parameters for the stored procedure? like the @doccount I have mentioned in sample code.